# Преобразование таблицы с сайта в словарь Python

Tags: python, парсер, словарь

Хотел бы создать словарь с данными из таблицы сайта

Код получения текста с таблицы:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    url = 'https://www.learnathome.ru/blog/sms-acronyms'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    quotes = soup.find_all('td')
    
    
    for quote in quotes:
        s = quote.text
```

Как выглядит таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как выглядит поток данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: есть проблемные места, BeautifulSoup и pandas их не обработают правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно так (если я правильно понял, что вы хотите):

```
data = ['aaa', '1', 'bbbb', '2', 'cc', '3']

dictionary = dict(zip(data[::2], data[1::2]))
```

или так:

```
dictionary = {data[i]:data[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)}
```

или так:

```
dictionary = dict(data[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2))
```

Comment: Смотрите, мне необходимо из данных, которые были получены с таблицы сайта, создать словарь, а именно: 1 столбик таблицы пускай будет x, 2 столбик y. Получается: abvs['x'] = 'y'

Comment: ну так мой код так и делает - из списка значений, которые вы привели формирует словарь

Comment: 1 вариант единственный, который работает без ошибок), однако он почему-то выводит символы поодиночке: {'U': 'p', ' ': 'Y', 'o': 'u', 'r': 's'}

Comment: все варианты работаю - просто у вас скорее всего СТРОКА, а не список - разбейте строку на список через `split()`, возможно у вас строка вида `"xxx\nyyy\nzzz\bnwww"` - поэтому предварительно сделайте `.split('\n')`

Answer (score 1):

[pandas.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) читает HTML-таблицы в pandas DataFrame

```
df = pandas.read_html(html_content, header=0, flavor='bs4')
dicts = df[0].to_dict('records')
```